# Qt MainWindow missing titlebar, maximize, minimize, and close buttons

Tags: c++, qt

I have a gui and for MainWindow it is missing the titlebar, maximize, minimize, and close buttons. It also cannot be resized. OS is linux, rhel 6.
I've checked all the settings in QtCreator and also in MainWindow.cpp, there are no entries for:

- setWindowFlags
- setSizePolicy
- setFixedSize
- setMaximumSize
- setMinimumSize

I tried to force it through,

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
setWindowTitle("Test1234");
```

But nothing!

Is there some kind of setting in QtCreator that is forcing this?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Note that the controls you mention -- titlebar, maximize, minimize, and close buttons etc. -- are generally provided by the window manager being used rather than the application itself.